# ui-data contracts: client side extended validation of json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonschema

I am in a few situations where json I am getting from services and database calls, created by another group, are giving me invalid data combinations, and causing many unintended errors downstream.

Given in the small example below, if the "rowContent" field is equal to "1", it's corresponding "row" needs to be a populated javascript object. "rowContent1" and "row1", and "rowContent2" and "row2" are correct. "rowContent3" and "row3" is not.

I concede the structure of this json is not fantastic. Ok it's a little wacky. It's fairly close to what I am dealing with in production. I have little control over it.

Are there data driven ways to describe json data relationships like this, that validate, before I start trying to use non-existent data in "row3"?

Or, what would you recommend I do in this situation?

thanks much,

-Larry

```
{ "table" : [
        { 
            "aRowContent" : {
                "rowContent1" : "1",
                "rowContent2" : "0",
                "rowContent3" : "1",
            },
            "row1" : {
                "myRowValue" : "red"
            },
            "row2" : null,
            "row3" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with JSON Schema, certainly.  JSON Schema validates the structure of JSON data without cross-referencing to other bits of data.

I think the issue might be the redundancy in your data structure- why do you need `/table/0/aRowContent/rowContent1` when you can deduce the same information from a null-check of `/table/0/row1`?

Comment: I understand that you don't have control over the format - however, it's that redundancy that stops it being properly validatable.

Comment: Agreed. The issue is with the structure of the json. Unfortunately this isn't my datastructure or I would fix this myself and use JSON Schema. Thx